# How to add Google Analytic code for subdomain?

Tags: google-analytics

I already added google analytic code in my main domain(abc.com) and want add google analytic code in the the subdomain (blog.abc.com).

Is any changes is require in main analytic code or have to add same analytic code.

Another question is how can i analyze my blog thorough Google analytic as in -  account - Behavior - site content - all pages tab it doesn't show sub domain.

I go through the google doc for the same and they mentioned that i have to do changes in analytic code which will look like following code

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example-petstore.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

My current analytic is

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Please guild me on the same

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Universal Analytics, then sub domain tracking is done automatically. You can simply add the same tracking snippet to all pages of the sub domain and make sure that you use 'auto' in the cookie domain (which you already have in your tracking snippet). This is a pretty standard question and no reason how you shouldn't have found it by a bit of searching.